# I can't get numbers to show up in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/HKhw8/67/

HTML:

```
<p>You can see this text... <span id="text"></span></p>
<p>...but not this: <span id="mathStuffs"></span></p>
<p>Number variables don't seem to show, either- <span id="num"></span></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var text = 'Hello'
var i = 50;
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = text;
document.getElementById('mathStuffs').innerHTML = math.pow(5,2);
document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = i;
```

The code doesn't show up in the preview like some of the nicely color-coded syntax highlighting like I've seen in previous posts- sorry about that.

I originally thought that console.log() was the problem, so I have this example set up. Regular text variables show up, but I can't seem to get the numbers or functions that return numbers to appear. Is there something I'm doing wrong? I've tried fiddling with the No wrap - in  setting, but I can't understand. I've tried Chrome and FF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`math` is not a class of javascript it should be `Math`

```
document.getElementById('mathStuffs').innerHTML = Math.pow(5,2);
```

Also one of the reference of a div is wrong

```
document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = i;
```

it should be `num`

```
 document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = i;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I knew it was something simple- This should be a good refresher about case sensitivity and JS for noobs like me. Interesting enough, the third number (with the id fix) didn't show up until I fixed the function.

Comment: good to know that you are motivated and interested in learning.. :) happy coding